# Bootable USB for MacOS Installation

Tags: macos, bootable-disk

Is it necessary to create the bootable USB from the same kind of device in which you wish to use it. I want to create one for my MBP (for which I have deleted the recovery drive as well) and I have a working Macbook Air.

So if I use my Air to create the drive for MBP, will it work?

Comment: Not to contradict Allan's answer, he knows way more than I and has helped me in the past. However, I personally was unsuccessful booting/installing with a MBP created USB drive on my mini, and was similarly unsuccessful booting/installing with a mini created USB drive on my MBP. Maybe I was doing something else wrong, but was only able to get a USB boot/install drive to work when created on the target machine.

Comment: What error did you used to get while recovering mac from a USB created from a different Mac?

Comment: I don't recall the exact message, it was something like "image corrupted - disk unusable" or "file corrupted." Sorry I don't remember better, it was a couple months ago and I didn't write it down - too busy scrambling to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a bootable USB from any machine capable of running a version of macOS that has access to the App Store.

If you use a MacBook Air running Yosemite, you can download the installer for High Sierra and use it to create the USB installer and then procede to use it on a MacBook Pro (and every other Mac that supports that version of macOS).

There's no specific installer for Mac hardware types.

(Personally, I keep a USB installer of every major version of macOS - Yosemite, El Capitan, Sierra, and High Sierra)

Comment: Do you have any idea why it shows this error? The operation couldn't be completed (com.apple.osinstallersetup.LinkFileDownload error 3.)

Comment: I have tried this many times and not been able to solve this. Please help. Once I was able to get ahead, but the installation failed later saying auth:failed to write to <private>

Comment: Do you have a good Internet connection?  Have you tried Internet recovery on the MacBook Pro?

Comment: I tried. Once it went to 200 blocks downloaded and stopped. Other times it remains stuck at the globe.

Comment: So, you don't have a good Internet connection.  Try going to a location with better connectivity and attempt to create the USB installer and/or do Internet recovery from there.